# How to get geolocation data with JavaCard from SIM

Tags: localization, geolocation, javacard

I would like to write a simple cardlet which takes geolocation data from my SIM card.

I read about JavaCard but I have no idea how I can use it to get geolocation.

I read that SIM cards keep the information about

> Local Area Identity

and I would like to get this data with my cardlet.

Could you suggest me some solutions(APIs) f.e. with JavaCard.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some possible (U)SIM Toolkit APIs:

1. Using `EVENT_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION_STATUS`. Register this event on install method, and applet will receive the event when there is location update in processToolkit method.
2. Using `PROVIDE_LOCAL_INFORMATION` proactive command, with command qualifier set to '00' ( Location Information / MCC, MNC, LAC and Cell Identity).

For two solutions above, you need to check that the mobile phone you are using has the support of the mechanism, indicated in its `TERMINAL PROFILE`.

Alternatively, you can also check for EF LOCI under DF GSM which keeps the Local Area Identity information and read it using `READ BINARY`.